# Rotated ellipse collision detection

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, collision-detection

Is there any way to check if two rotated ellipses are colliding? I am using node.js and socket.io to build a simple game and I need to describe an object with ellipse. is there any way to do it using simple javascript with no libraries? (PS. I've been googling for it so long)...

Comment: Are you using SVG or something like that? If you have center coordinates, length and width, and the angle, you can calculate if they're touching.

Comment: I am using 2d canvas, can you please show me how to calculate if they're touching? I have length width and angle :)

Comment: Well, I can't because I don't know all formulas, but I can give you basics of the method. You'll need 5 informations per ellipse: `minor_radius`, `major_radius`, `center_x`, `center_y`, `rotation_angle`. From these, you'll need to use Pythagore formula and `center_x` and `center_y` of both ellipse to know the distance between the ellipses centers. If the distance is greater than the sum of their `major_radius`, they can't touch. If it's shorter than the sum of their `minor_radius`, they touch necessarily. The difficult part is the inbetween.

Comment: For the inbetween, you'll have to calculate the "intermediary_radius" using both the `rotation_angle` and the "angle_between_ellipses" with some cosinus/sinus involved maybe. I don't know the formula of the "intermediary_radius", so I can't help you with that case.

Comment: Somebody who can help with this intermediary_radius? this time it seems clear what you are saying. I understand everything you've mentioned.